# How to make combojack work properly with cs4208 soundcard on a macbook pro late 2013 with Linux Mint 20?

Tags: linux-mint, audio, macintosh, microphone, jack

I have a macbook pro late 2013 (macbookpro 11,1) with Linux Mint 20, kernel 5.4.0-58-generic

The soundcard is Cirrus Logic cs4208. The issue I have is that the headset microphone isn't recognized. I've tried mainly changing the model part in the `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf but there seems not to be my particular model in this list https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/sound/hd-audio/models.html#cirrus-logic-cs4208

Does someone know how to help me or is this a vain hope (it maybe, based on this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1393502)?